# osmnx query OpenStreetMap

Tags: python, graph, networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am using **Python** and I am trying to use **osmnx** to query **OpenStreetMap** and get data about the Italian city of [**Brescia**](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/45144#map=12/45.5354/10.2236).

Here's the code I copied from the docs.

```
import osmnx as ox

place = "Brescia, Italy"
osmnx_buffer = 10000 # in metres
g = ox.graph.graph_from_place(place, buffer_dist=osmnx_buffer)
g = ox.projection.project_graph(g)

ox.plot_graph(g)
```

The only thing I changed is the content of the string `place`.

The problem is that when I run the script, it never replies (and therefore, never plots anything). I tried to read the documentation and change my query, but I do not know what is wrong with it. Can you please suggest me how to make this script work?

My objective is to work on it with `networkx`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your python library does not offer an error message you could look at? Open street map always replies, if only with a cryptic error message.  But sometimes the message will tell you what is going wrong.  I find that testing queries using overpass turbo can sort out a lot of problems https://overpass-turbo.eu/

Comment: @ravenspoint unfortunately, I am sure. The execution never ends.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a bug in the library, or perhaps just really bad design.  Perhaps you should try querying the open street map database directly?  Have you tried using overpass turbo?

Comment: @ravenspoint sorry, I don't understand. How would you do it so that networkx works with it?

Comment: I use overpass turbo to debug my queries, and work out how to parse the response.  Then, when I know the query is correct I use libCurl to integrate the query with the rest of my code and design the response parsing.

Comment: OSMnx provides logging so you can see exactly what it's doing. See the documentation for details. Provide the log output here as an edit and we can troubleshoot it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything appears to be working fine with your code (I just ran it successfully). But note that your `buffer_dist` function parameter you're passing is deprecated. Also, turn on OSMnx logging if you're ever wondering what it's doing. It takes a couple minutes to build the full model of ~2.5 million nodes and ~5 million edges, then do all the proper truncation and topological correction.

Here's example code plus logging output:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.log_console = True  # turn on logging
place = "Brescia, Italy"

# buffer the study area by 10 km
geom = ox.geocode_to_gdf(place).iloc[0]["geometry"]
geom_proj, crs = ox.projection.project_geometry(geom)
geom_buff, _ = ox.projection.project_geometry(geom_proj.buffer(10000), crs=crs, to_latlong=True)

# get the graph and plot it
G = ox.graph_from_polygon(geom_buff)
Gp = ox.project_graph(G)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(Gp)
```

and the log output:

```
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Retrieved response from cache file 'cache/39adbce181a495e998c06fd21bd65ad28d80e3d3.json'
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Created GeoDataFrame with 1 rows from 1 queries
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Projected GeoDataFrame to 'EPSG:32632 / WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N'
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Projected GeoDataFrame to 'EPSG:4326 / WGS 84'
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Projected GeoDataFrame to 'EPSG:32632 / WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N'
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Projected GeoDataFrame to 'EPSG:4326 / WGS 84'
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Projected GeoDataFrame to 'EPSG:32632 / WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N'
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Projected GeoDataFrame to 'EPSG:4326 / WGS 84'
2023-12-20 12:45:56 Requesting data from API in 6 request(s)
2023-12-20 12:45:57 Retrieved response from cache file 'cache/2e7b530676d51fb707ca5d490cea53497b235300.json'
2023-12-20 12:45:57 Retrieved response from cache file 'cache/ee58a27f7c210838eafe3cc95e2470d884a9582e.json'
2023-12-20 12:45:58 Retrieved response from cache file 'cache/8d11d09ff31df390c9837d54ee33d55d005e8fa5.json'
2023-12-20 12:45:59 Retrieved response from cache file 'cache/9a85fc97fe64f2d6acbdf37b8476f36ed11e98cd.json'
2023-12-20 12:46:00 Retrieved response from cache file 'cache/0636bb65f47203267ae6843d3abd4b2ed812ed9e.json'
2023-12-20 12:46:00 Retrieved response from cache file 'cache/0f4b714e6f9cd7bcabe129c5c6a294fc104b5381.json'
2023-12-20 12:46:00 Retrieved all data from API in 6 request(s)
2023-12-20 12:46:00 Creating graph from 2,465,008 OSM nodes and 271,692 OSM ways...
2023-12-20 12:46:20 Created graph with 2,465,008 nodes and 4,944,897 edges
2023-12-20 12:46:30 Added length attributes to graph edges
2023-12-20 12:46:30 Identifying all nodes that lie outside the polygon...
2023-12-20 12:46:45 Created nodes GeoDataFrame from graph
2023-12-20 12:46:45 Created r-tree spatial index for 2,465,008 geometries
2023-12-20 12:46:46 Identified 2,142,413 geometries inside polygon
2023-12-20 12:47:05 Removed 322,595 nodes outside polygon
2023-12-20 12:47:05 Truncated graph by polygon
2023-12-20 12:47:05 Begin topologically simplifying the graph...
2023-12-20 12:47:27 Identified 283,430 edge endpoints
2023-12-20 12:48:19 Simplified graph: 2,142,413 to 283,430 nodes, 4,294,956 to 686,891 edges
2023-12-20 12:48:19 Identifying all nodes that lie outside the polygon...
2023-12-20 12:48:21 Created nodes GeoDataFrame from graph
2023-12-20 12:48:21 Created r-tree spatial index for 283,430 geometries
2023-12-20 12:48:21 Identified 276,578 geometries inside polygon
2023-12-20 12:48:25 Removed 6,852 nodes outside polygon
2023-12-20 12:48:28 Removed 79 isolated nodes
2023-12-20 12:48:36 Got largest weakly connected component (272,847 of 276,499 total nodes)
2023-12-20 12:48:36 Truncated graph by polygon
2023-12-20 12:48:37 Counted undirected street segments incident on each node
2023-12-20 12:48:38 graph_from_polygon returned graph with 272,847 nodes and 665,586 edges
2023-12-20 12:48:39 Created nodes GeoDataFrame from graph
2023-12-20 12:48:42 Projected GeoDataFrame to 'EPSG:32632 / WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N'
2023-12-20 12:48:46 Created edges GeoDataFrame from graph
2023-12-20 12:48:47 Projected GeoDataFrame to 'EPSG:32632 / WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N'
2023-12-20 12:48:56 Created graph from node/edge GeoDataFrames
2023-12-20 12:48:57 Projected graph with 272847 nodes and 665586 edges
2023-12-20 12:48:57 Begin plotting the graph...
2023-12-20 12:49:06 Created edges GeoDataFrame from graph
2023-12-20 12:49:15 Created nodes GeoDataFrame from graph
2023-12-20 12:49:19 Finished plotting the graph
```

Comment: Dear @gboeing, thank you for your precious help. The logging provides a helpful insight in what is happening. Unfortunately, your code takes almost 2 hours to be runned on my pc, and returns an area which is way superior than the city of Brescia. Supposing I want the exact bouds of the Italian town, how can I modify the query? Thank you

Comment: Don't buffer the geometry by 10km like you were doing if you don't want your result to be way larger than Brescia's boundaries.